# Memory corruption (0xC0000005 - Application Error) using Modules in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

I've switched over to using the new Modules in Visual Studio (2019 - 16.10.4). Everything compiles and runs just fine if I do a full compilation (i.e. Clean the solution first). Very often when I compile normally, though, I get a crash or initialisation. The error is `Application Error` (0xC0000005) and appears on startup.

In x86, there's no valid call stack to look at at all. In x64, the debugger points to a valid call stack, at `exe_common.inl` in a line that says `__scrt_current_native_startup_state = __scrt_native_startup_state::initialized;`. I realise that's a red herring, and the actual line is `_initterm(__xc_a, __xc_z);` which I understand is the global memory initialisation.

Is anyone aware of such issues with Modules in VC? The internet doesn't have much information on this case, which leads me to believe it has to do with various configuration options that I might be using. Any pointers? I'm really hoping I won't have to stop using Modules, which I was really looking forward to. There is also a slight chance a recent update to Visual Studio or perhaps something obscure I might have done in the conversion to Modules that is the culprit.

It's just strange that it's guaranteed to work with a full compilation, which would lead me to think that the compiler is to blame.

Comment: Just updated to 16.11.0 and it now need a recompilation more often with errors in different places, so it's looking like a serious but rare-ish bug in Visual Studio